# Error while uploading images to Cloudinary from the front-end and store the data in a MySQL database with the use Axios on Node JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, axios, cloudinary

I am creating a web app with React. There's a form which users can input text data and multiple image files. I need to upload the submitted images to Cloudinary and store the Cloudinary Image URL and other text data in a MySQL database.

However there's an error. The image files don’t pass to the server. I assume that my implementation has to be changed for the image inputs but figured out how exactly. May I know a solution for this? Thank you!

Client

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Axios from 'axios';

function Verify() {
    // Text Inputs
    const [address, setAddress] = useState("")
    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    const [nic, setNIC] = useState("")
    // Image inputs
    const [nicfront, setNICFront] = useState("")
    const [nicback, setNICBack] = useState("")
    const [selfie, setSelfie] = useState("")

    const submitApplication = () => {
        console.log("start")
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/create', {
            address: address,
            name: name,
            nic: nic,
            nicfront: nicfront,
            nicback: nicback,
            selfie: selfie
        }).then(() => {
            console.log("Success")
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            <section>
                <label>Address</label>
                <input type="text" onChange={(event) => { setAddress(event.target.value) }} />

                <label>Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" onChange={(event) => { setName(event.target.value) }} />

                <label>NIC Number</label>
                <input type="text" onChange={(event) => { setNIC(event.target.value) }} />


                <label>NIC Front</label>
                <input id="imagefront" name="imagefront" type="file" onChange={(event) => { setNICFront(event.target.value) }} />

                <label>NIC Back</label>
                <input id="imagefront" name="imagefront" type="file" onChange={(event) => { setNICBack(event.target.value) }} />

                <label>Upload a selfie with the NIC</label>
                <input id="imagefront" name="imagefront" type="file" onChange={(event) => { setSelfie(event.target.value) }} />

                <div>
                    <div class="control">
                        <button onClick={submitApplication} >Submit for Review</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </>
    );
}
export default Verify;
```

Server

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
require('dotenv').config();

const cl_user = process.env.CLUSER;
const cl_key = process.env.CLKEY;
const cl_secret = process.env.CLSECRET;

const app = express()
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//  Cloudinary intergration
cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: cl_user,
    api_key: cl_key,
    api_secret: cl_secret
});

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'blockverify'
})

app.post('/create', (req, res) => {
    var wallet = ""
    var name = ""
    var nic = ""
    var nicfront = ""
    var nicback = ""
    var selfie = ""
    var state = 1

    // Retrieving data from the client
    wallet = req.body.address
    name = req.body.name
    nic = req.body.nic

    nicfront = req.body.nicfront
    nicback = req.body.nicback
    selfie = req.body.selfie

    cloudinary.uploader.upload(nicfront.tempFilePath, function (err, result) {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
        console.log("Result: ", result);
        var frontURL = result.secure_url;

    });

    cloudinary.uploader.upload(nicback.tempFilePath, function (err, result) {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
        console.log("Result: ", result);
        var backURL = result.secure_url;

    });

    cloudinary.uploader.upload(selfie.tempFilePath, function (err, result) {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
        console.log("Result: ", result);
        var selfieURL = result.secure_url;

    });

    db.query("INSERT INTO applications (wallet, name, nic, nicfront, nicback, selfie, state) VALUE (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", [wallet, name, nic, nicfurl, nicback, selfie, state], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.send("Inserted!")
        }
    })
})

app.listen(3001, () => {
    db.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected to MySQL!");
    });
});
```

Following is the error.

```
Error:  {
  message: 'Missing required parameter - file',
  name: 'Error',
  http_code: 400
}
Result:  undefined
/Users/sandaru/DATA DRIVE/Degree/L6/FYP/Project/block-verify/server/index.js:50
        var frontURL = result.secure_url;
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'secure_url')
    at /Users/sandaru/DATA DRIVE/Degree/L6/FYP/Project/block-verify/server/index.js:50:31
    at /Users/sandaru/DATA DRIVE/Degree/L6/FYP/Project/block-verify/server/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/utils/index.js:1259:14
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/sandaru/DATA DRIVE/Degree/L6/FYP/Project/block-verify/server/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/uploader.js:507:9)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey there it looks like you might be having issues with your file.

Options for a file to upload. It can be:

- a local file path (supported in SDKs only)
- the actual data (byte array buffer). For example, in some SDKs, this
  could be an IO input stream of the data (e.g., File.open(file,
  "rb")).
- the Data URI (Base64 encoded), max ~60 MB (62,910,000 chars)
- the remote FTP, HTTP or HTTPS URL address of an existing file
- a private storage bucket (S3 or Google Storage) URL of a whitelisted
  bucket

Look at some examples,
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#file_source_options

Comment: i have same flow o saving images in cloudinary and then whole data in db. i am able to add everything successfully, other times i get network error or Error [ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT]: Socket connection timeout

Comment: @VeerPratap It's hard to say conclusively without more information. I would recommend opening a support ticket. Support@cloudinary.com, provide cloud_name and as much information as possible.